# How can i access a listbox from another pc in C#

Tags: c#

This is a local chat application, my problem is that when i run two instances of the application on the same pc is working but when i want to chat between two pc's i get this error in the image below[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzUwP.png). i know it's a thread problem and this code must be change so anyone can help?

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] recieveData = new byte[1500];
            recieveData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

            ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string recievedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(recieveData);

            listMessage.Items.Add("Friend: " + recievedMessage);

            buffer = new byte[1500];
            sok.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref             epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your exception as text; it contains useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListMessage is an item you've created on the UI thread. You can't update it from another thread. I would use the dispatcher.begininvoke method.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
{ 
    ListMessage.Items.Add(string.Format("Friend: {0}", recievedMessage)) 
}));
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i import System.Windows.Threading but the Dispatcher is missing in the context ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to WindowsBase in your project?

Comment: done, but then this error
An object reference is required to access non-static member..

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the static property Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher to get the instance of the dispatcher for the current thread and then call BeginInvoke on that instance. Either that or somehow get a dispatcher instance to your method from the particular thread you want to call to.

Comment: if you mean like this " Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
               {
                   listMessage.Items.Add(string.Format("Friend: {0}", recievedMessage));
               })); "
it does not work too

Comment: listMessage.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
               {
                   listMessage.Items.Add(string.Format("Friend: {0}", recievedMessage));
               }));
this is solve the error. Thanks Bram very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

the data you get it from is coming from another non UIThread, that is the reason you are getting this `Exception` and there you can not change UI Controls.

**Solution :**  You can use `InvokeRequired`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method when  making
>   method calls to the control because the caller is
>   on a different  thread than the one the control was created on.

Replace This:

```
listMessage.Items.Add("Friend: " + recievedMessage);
```

with this:

```
       if(this.listMessage.InvokeRequired)
        {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
        listMessage.Items.Add("Friend: " + recievedMessage);
        });
         }
```

Comment: listMessage.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
               {
                   listMessage.Items.Add(string.Format("Friend: {0}", recievedMessage));
               }));
this is solve the issue. Thanks Sudhakar for your help